# Swift not Parsing JSON from PHP Server

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I am writing a simple application for iOS in swift that makes an ajax call to a server of mine. Here is the relevant swift code:

```
class Request : NSObject {
    func send(url: String, f: (NSData)-> ()) {
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: error)
        //var reply = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        f(data!)
    }
}

class myObj: NSObject {

    let baseURL: String
    var message: String

    init() {        
        self.baseURL = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
        self.message = "No Message"
    }

    func check() -> Bool {

        let locationURL = self.baseURL

        self.message = locationURL
        var request = Request()
        request.send(locationURL, f: {(result: NSData)-> () in
            let jsonData: NSData = result
            var error: NSError?

            let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSDictionary
            self.message = jsonDict["title"] as! String
        })

        return true
    }
}
```

Here is the server side code that I return dummy JSON with:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    if(isset($_GET['location'])) {
        echo json_encode(Array( 'success' => true, 'message' => 'I came from the server.', 'title' => 'tittttt'));
    } else if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
        echo json_encode(Array( 'success' => true, 'message' => 'message received', 'title' => 'ttt'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(Array( 'success' => false, 'message' => 'invalid params', 'title' => 'title from server'));
    }
?>
```

When I switch out my URL for a dummy json url (I am using http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1?a=b) it works; when I use my own URL it fails with the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here is the actual JSON response from the server:

> {
>       success: true,
>       message: "I came from the server.",
>       title: "tit-le" }

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: On the line: `let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSDictionary`

Comment: Your php appears to be returning an array and your swift appears to be forcing it to be a dictionary

Comment: This seems like your PHP response is malformed in some way, although it is not due your use of PHP's array, as that's how PHP handles dictionaries. Frank, can you post a sample response (with redacted/modified data if needed)?

Comment: @wain I tried casting the NSJSONSerialization as an NSArray and getting the first element, no dice.

Comment: What is the error info from NSError?

Comment: @FrankConry I checked your code in playground and it works fine. At least with URL http://stik.li/api2.php?location=test I'm getting `tit-le` in message property.

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); <---- Does your PHP have this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have u tried adding
    `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`
To your PHP

Comment: Wohooo.. OK so just to explain.. This is to allow cross domain connection. Any requests which are not from the same domain are usually blocked. This allows the request to come through.